# Making host-resolved environment variables work with fig on boot2docker

Tags: boot2docker, fig

According to the [fig YML reference](http://www.fig.sh/yml.html#environment), I should be able to declare an environment variable with only a key to resolve this to the corresponding variable on the host. That doesn't work for me in boot2docker.

Here's my fig.yml:

```
test:
    image: ubuntu
    command: env
    environment:
        TESTVAR:
```

I'm running `TESTVAR=foo fig up` and I'm getting the following output:

```
test_1 | TESTVAR=
```

I suspect this is because I'm using the fig container with the alias from [fig #598](https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/598#issuecomment-67762456) in boot2docker, which probably doesn't pass the environment variables through properly. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value should be getting picked up from the environment where fig is run using https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ

Looking at that alias, it does look like the fig command actually gets run in a container, so I think you're right.

You could modify the alias to pass in other environment variables using

```
-e TESTVAR=$(TESTVAR)
```

Comment: Duh, of course, I could have seen that myself… Even easier, I can do just `-e TESTVAR` (without giving it a value) and docker will take the value from the host.